# How do you center a graphic in a cell on a full screen black background by code rather than menu items?

Tags: graphics, front-end, video

I have a 1080 x 1080 dynamic MatrixPlot which centers nicely on a black background, full screen height and width, by the use of menu items. I would prefer to set up that cell by code w/o the use of menu items.  I'd also like to get rid of "Out=" to the left, and the cell selection brace to the right.  The idea is to setup the graphic for video screen capture with the Win 10 Xbox Game App so no further editing is required after it is imported into Adobe Premier Pro.

Comment: You can also export directly to most video formats from Mathematica. If you have FFMPEG installed, I think you can export to any format that it supports.

Comment: @MassDefect - Are you able to take 2 passes through the video, one to survey levels of compression, and the second to render the video?  Adobe Rush was single pass, and I am starting to use Premier Pro.  If FFMPEG has two passes and you can control bitrate, I will try it.

Comment: In my original post, I should have said: "no further editing by way of cropping or image background colorization outside the centered graphic", so doing that in Mathematica will minimize video editor work.